# Debian Jessie 8.2 aborts with an Application Error in VirtualBox

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I recently installed Debian Jessie 8.2 using dvd-1 (that is debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) on VirtualBox version 4.3.22 with gdm3 as the display manager and GNOME as the desktop environment. My host OS is Windows 7. It was working fine, until I tried to install Guest Additions with [these](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/) instructions to try to enable full screen. Another major thing that I did before this error, was to edit the sources.list file (commented out the deb cdrom line) to solve an apt-get install error. Now, the full-screen functionality works fine, that is I can login successfully, and enter the Desktop, but every time I click on Activities on the top-left corner, and afterwards on any one of the icons in the left toolbar, it aborts with an application error that looks like this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this, its my first time on Debian, and I am new to Linux as well.

Comment: The problem here is that it's your VirtualBox that's crashing and that is running on Windows, meaning the question isn't on the correct site. Super User might be a better choice.  Meanwhile, have you considered upgrading VirtualBox to version 5?

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks for the pointer, I'll post it there. No, I haven't, could that be the reason? I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on the same VirtualBox tho, and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Upgrading is worth a shot.  Nothing to lose and it adds quite a few extra features, such as USB 3 and the ability to disconnect the session and keep the VM running in the background.

Comment: Will try doing that!

Comment: @garethTheRed Just updated to version 5, gives the same error.

Comment: Interesting.  I'd raise a bug report against this with Oracle. It could be VirtualBox's 3D support, but you can't disable that as it's needed for Gnome.  You could try a distro that doesn't use Gnome 3 and disable 3D support.  KDE? Gnome 2? etc

Comment: @garethTheRed I'll look into how to raise a bug report. Just now, following your advice, I switched to 'Gnome Classic' on the login screen (on the same distro). Just switched without disabling 3D support, and its working! that is the Terminal and other applications open without raising the VirtualBox Application error. Yay! Thanks so much. I will research more about VB's 3D support though, why it isn't working.